# Naming Convention for Storyboard Segues

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, naming-conventions, uistoryboardsegue

Having written a couple of iOS apps now, I have struggled to find a naming convention that made me happy for storyboard segues. I have toyed with a literal approach (e.g. `PushXYZController`) or a more detached intentional approach (e.g. `ToXYZEdit`). And I'm undecided whether to use `camelCase` or `StudlyCaps` as well.

I'm looking for an answer that suggests a naming convention with a convincing justification for why that convention is used vs others.

Answer (score 1):

I always name my segues with the convention `toViewControllerName` as in `toOrderGuideViewController`. It's only a convention, however, meaning that the purpose of me using camel case with lowercase first letter is merely for *consistency*.

As for my reasoning, I like to write in camel case with lowercase first letter because I reactively do that for variable names, keeping the muscle memory is a plus.

Or you could think of it like this:

`OrderGuideViewController` is the name of the swift file. `to` is just a prefix. Since it's not part of the name, it does not receive an uppercase T, for it's not a proper noun.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used this convention: Login->Dashboard